# Xml transform with HTML in the source only returns text

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have an Xml transformation I need to do, but am having a bit of a struggle.

The input Xml looks like this...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<content>
     <div>Stuff Goes Here</div>
</content>
```

And the stylesheet looks like this...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'      xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'  exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'>

<xsl:output method='html' />
     <xsl:template match='/'>
          <xsl:value-of select='content' disable-output-escaping='yes'   />
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have got the transform working with c#, but it only returns **"Stuff Goes Here"** without the wrapping div tag.

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it be "<div>Stuff Goes Here</div>", as opposed to just "Stuff Goes Here"?

Comment: Yes, it should be <div>Stuff Goes Here</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<xsl:output method='html' />
<xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:copy-of select='content/div'/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs

```
<div>Stuff here</div>
```

Good Luck